# How can I reshape a Theano tensor to one dimension by using the function flatten()

Tags: tensorflow, keras, theano

`import theano.tensor as T
 from keras import backend as K`

`test=T.tensor4('test')
 test=K.flatten(test)`

but I get this question:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-29-73f70b604492>", line 1, in <module>
    y_true = K.flatten(test)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 1929, in flatten
    return tf.reshape(x, [-1])

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_array_ops.py", line 2510, in reshape
    name=name)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 494, in apply_op
    raise err

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 491, in apply_op
    preferred_dtype=default_dtype)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 704, in internal_convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 113, in _constant_tensor_conversion_function
    return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 102, in constant
    tensor_util.make_tensor_proto(value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape, verify_shape=verify_shape))

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_util.py", line 444, in make_tensor_proto
    tensor_proto.string_val.extend([compat.as_bytes(x) for x in proto_values])

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_util.py", line 444, in <listcomp>
    tensor_proto.string_val.extend([compat.as_bytes(x) for x in proto_values])

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\compat.py", line 65, in as_bytes
    (bytes_or_text,))

TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got test
```

Comment: You're mixing two different backends, tensorflow and theano. I don't think this will ever work properly. --- If you intend to work with theano, I suggest you to use an independent keras installation (not the one that comes in tensorflow) and set its backend to theano.

Comment: Thank you very much. I change the theano backend to keras, and that works!